# Modulus of large powers

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, modular-arithmetic

Given an array of N integers where $2 ≤ N ≤ 2×10^5$ and each element in array is less than $10^{16}$.
Now I am given a variable $X$ that can also go up to $10^{16}$.

We need to find if $X \mid A_0^{A_1^{A_2^{\unicode{x22f0}^{A_N}}}}$.

How to solve this problem?

Obviously computing the power here is not feasible.

Comment: I think its good to factorize both both $A_0$ and $X$.

Comment: And toalso know the factorization of $\phi(X)$, $\phi(\phi(X))$ et cetera. At this range of $X$ that shouldn't prove to be too difficult. But were does this problem come from? Feels a bit unnatural. I've only seen questions like this in programming contests.

Comment: @hanu  How to factorise such a large number ?

Comment: @user3923257 Actually its enough to factorize the $gcd(X,A_0)$

Comment: @hanu Please elaborate your approach

Comment: @hanu How its enough to factorize the gcd(X,A0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Calculate $g=gcd(A_o,X)$.

2) Factorize $g$.

3) Select smallest among $A_0$ and $X$, let it be $X$.

4) For each distinct prime factor $p$ of $g$

4.1) Find arity $r$ (power of that prime number $p$ in $X$) of $p$ with respect to $X$.

4.2) Divide $X$ with $p^r$ for each such $p$ and store the result in $X$.

5) Now our $X$ is free from all common prime factors with $A_0$, So now if our resulted $X\ne 1$ then it contains a prime number that is not in $A_0$, so then $X \nmid A_0$.

Note : Finding arity of a prime number can be achieved in lesser time (order of arity ).

Example : $X=3^3*5^9*7^2$ and $A_0 = 3^2*5^{11}*11^3$

1)$gcd=g=3^2*5^9$

2) 3,5 are prime factors of $g$.

3) select either $X$or $A_0$ .(no restriction on minimum of both).

4) if you select $X$ then $X$ becomes $7^2$ else if u select $A_0$, it becomes $11^3$ . (we are dividing with prime factors of $g$ ).

5) Now if you select $X$,$X\ne 1$ , so $X$ has prime factor(7) that is not in $A_0$. similarly for $A_0$.

Comment: What is arity?And how are you factorising number of range 10^16

Comment: @user3923257 Arity is the power of a prime in a number. suppose 3 has arity 2 and 2 has arity 3 in 72 . since $72=3^2*2^3$ ,

Comment: What if minimum of two is A[0] ?

Comment: @user3923257 Actually , there is no problem if you select either $A_0$ or $X$ . But to run in less time selecting smallest in step 3 may be useful . If $A_0$is smallest one , then apply step 4,5 for  $A_0$ instead of $X$.

Comment: Please provide an example.Am getting confused

Comment: @user3923257 I did now.

Comment: what you did is just check whether X is the divisor of A0, isn't it? Even if it is not, X may still be a divisor of A0^A1

Answer (score 0):

Let $B_0 = A_0$ and compute $B_{n+1} = B_n / gcd (B_n, X)$ until you reach two identical values for $B_n$ (which will happen for $n \le \log (10^{16})/\log 2 \le 54$)

Say $B_n = B_{n+1}$.
If $B_n = 1$, then $X$ divides $A_0^n$ (and clearly, $A_1^{A_2^\ldots}$ is greater than $n$ most of the time).
If $B_n \neq 1$, then $X$ has prime factors not occuring in $A_0$ so $X$ doesn't divide any $A_0^p$ for any $p$.

Comment: @mecio I dont get your approach.Please explain

Comment: I dont get your approach.Please explain

Comment: What if Their is not such n such that B[n]=B[n+1] .Then ?

Comment: $B_n$ is a decreasing sequence of positive integers so it can't be strictly decreasing indefinitely. And of course once $B_n = B_{n+1}$ the sequence is stationary after that. What you get at the end is $A_0$ with every prime factor present in $X$ removed as much as possible, so it leaves only the prime factors of $A_0$ that are not in $X$

Comment: How is your answer indepedent of all remaining A[i]s.?Say we have array as [4 0 1] and X=8 then what ?

Comment: Also what for test case N=2 and array be [4 1] and X=8 ?Your code will give YES for this case too

Comment: well yes you have to check if $A_1^{A_2^\ldots}$ is greater or equal than $n$, which is relatively easy. In most cases, it will be.